# How to interpret the phase plot from an accelerometer on vibrating machinery

Tags: mechanical-engineering, vibration, turbomachinery

Attached is a plot of amplitude vs frequency and on the inset phase vs frequency. I have constructed this phase plot via $\arctan\left(\frac{Im}{Re}\right)$

How can I interpret the phase plot or extract some meaningful info from it, particularly in the region of the `almost vertical line`? This line occurs at around 102Hz which is nowhere near the amplitude peaks.

[image]

Comment: What is the system you present the amplitude vs frequency plot? Is it some rotating shaft?

Comment: mounted on a bracket as part of engine assembly

Comment: This has been common technology for rotating equipment for decades . I think you could find more analysis information under "rotating machinery"'

Answer (score 1):

I'm not an expert, but that vertical line in the phase is usually when transitioning over a critical rotational velocity of a shaft.

This happens when the excitation frequency "transverses" the critical frequency of the shaft. The [displacement of the shaft can be derived](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9Ojzsd5qYKY&t=31s) for an ideal motor (no damping):

$$ y = \frac{e\cdot \omega^2}{\omega_n^2 - \omega^2}  = \frac{e}{\frac{\omega_n^2}{ \omega^2} - 1}  $$

while a more advanced approach, with the inclusion of damping, calculates the dynamic magnifier as :

$$H(r,\zeta) = \frac{r^2}{\sqrt{(1-r^2)^2 + (2\zeta r)^2}}$$

the phase angle can be estimated by a similar expression  as:

$$\phi = \arctan\left(\frac{2\zeta r}{1- r^2}\right)$$

where:

- $\zeta$: is the damping ratio
- $r=\frac{\omega}{\omega_n}$

So when passing through the natural frequency $\omega_n$ what happens is that :

- (usually )you get a maximum value of the displacement
- you get an inversion of the phase angle $\phi$ (the ratio becomes greater than 1).

So what you are seeing in this graph at about 115[Hz]$\approx 6900rpm$, is that you pass through the critical speed of the shaft.

The earlier peak  (at about  95Hz) is probably another natural frequency of the engine assembly.

Comment: Thanks for this insight. The frequency range is fron a “run  down” speed sweep. So perhaps we are passing through shaft natural frequencies which is picked up on the bracket.